# file_get_contents() works differently on different machines

Tags: php, ssl, file-get-contents

I have written a piece of php code to use `file_get_contents()` to download a .js file from a site and try to run the code from 2 different machines and they produce different results.  The code is:

```
$link = "https://www.scotchwhiskyauctions.com/scripting/store-scripting_frontend.js";

$options = array(
  'http'=>array(
     'method'=>"GET",
     'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"  ),
  'ssl'=>array(
     'verify_peer'=>false,
     'verify_peer_name'=>false),
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$line = file_get_contents($link, false, $context);
var_dump($http_response_header);
echo $line;
exit;
```

When I run this piece of code in a Debian 8.11 machine it produces the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://www.scotchwhiskyauctions.com/scripting/store-scripting_frontend.js): failed to open stream: Connection timed out in /var/www/test.php on line 4
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: http_response_header in /var/www/test.php on line 4
NULL
```

However when I ran the exact same code on a different machine (Debian 4.16.12-1kali1) it can obtain the file content and the variable `$http_response_header` contains all the response header.  Both machines use php7.2.  After spending days trying to figure out what causes the Debian 8.11 machine to not be able to read the file, I used `wget` on both machines, and noticed that again, the Debian 8.11 (jessie) machine failed to read the file.

I suspected it has something to do with the ssl certificates so I ran

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
sudo update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

but it does not help at all.

Can anyone please point me to some direction?

Comment: Where do you define `$http_response_header` ?

Comment: @Dormilich `$http_response_header` is automatically filled - you don't have to define it: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is set to On in the `php.ini` file of both machines, just FYI.

Comment: @albertma789 Can you access the URL at all? (Using a browser f.e.)

Comment: @Xatenev yes I can.

Comment: Could be an IPV4/6 problem - you could try to bind the strem context to ipv4 with: `'socket' => ['bindto' => '0:0']`

Comment: @Philipp just tried. Didn't work.

Comment: @albertma789 `tcpdump -nni any host 111.111.111.111 and port 80` where `111.111.111.111` is the IP of whatever you are trying to reach. Then execute your script again and paste the output. To make sure the HTTP Request arrives at your server properly.

Comment: @Xatenev I used `tcpdump -w 1.pcap -nni any host 5.57.59.196 &` and then run my script, then I noticed the 1.pcap is empty.... strange... looks like it can't catch any packet apart from my own...

Comment: @Xatenev is there a verbose mode to see what file_get_contents() is doing behind the scene?

Comment: @Xatenev ok I got it.  Please see below:

`reading from file 1.pcap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)`
`18:13:15.239586 IP debian.59581 > 5.57.59.196.https: Flags [S], seq 2760997044, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2540286 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`
`18:13:16.235896 IP debian.59581 > 5.57.59.196.https: Flags [S], seq 2760997044, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2540536 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`
`18:13:18.239889 IP debian.59581 > 5.57.59.196.https: Flags [S], seq 2760997044, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2541037 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0`

Comment: @Xatenev the captured results of a wget session to the same server is similar.

Comment: the TCP sequence number does not increase (2760997044) - seems like your packets do not get through to the other host. Packet lengths are 0, too. Can you try a `traceroute` or `telnet` to the given host?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the problem fixed by following someone's comment on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/213264/cant-access-select-websites-on-linux-but-can-on-windows)

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps
```

I found the following in the [Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/docs/HOWTO/other-formats/html_single/Adv-Routing-HOWTO.html) article.

*/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_timestamps*

*Timestamps are used, amongst other things, to protect against
wrapping sequence numbers. A 1 gigabit link might conceivably
re-encounter a previous sequence number with an out-of-line value,
because it was of a previous generation. The timestamp will let it
recognize this 'ancient packet'.*

However I have no idea why it works. Can someone please explain?